# Jquery to hide table cell contents

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have a table that is laid out like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>checkbox</td>
    <td>text-text-text</td>
    <td>dropdownlist</td>
    <td>textbox</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to toggle visiblity of the dropdown list and textbox based on the check status of the checkbox.  I've got a click event set up that does this correctly, but it does not persist the visibilty of the rows when new data is loaded.  How can I do this in Jquery?

Edit: This is the function that's hooked up to the click event on the checkbox.  It toggles visibility of the elemtns correctly.  The problem I'm having is getting new rows loaded from the database to start out with the correct visibility.  (I'm using a repeater control in asp.net to build the table, so I'm passing in the client IDs into the function).

Simplified: I have a table with a checkbox in the first cell of each row, what selector in jquery would i use to get at the contents of the rest of the cells in that row, from the checkbox.

```
 function ToggleVisibility(position, hometown, state, checkbox, name, license) {
        if ($("#" + checkbox)[0].checked) {
            $("#" + position).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn('slow');
            $("#" + hometown).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn('slow');
            $("#" + state).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn('slow');
            $("#" + name).css('font-weight', 'bold');
            $("#" + license).css('font-weight', 'bold');
        }
        else {
            $("#" + position).css('visibility', 'hidden').fadeOut('slow');
            $("#" + hometown).css('visibility', 'hidden').fadeOut('slow');
            $("#" + state).css('visibility', 'hidden').fadeOut('slow');
            $("#" + name).css('font-weight', 'normal');
            $("#" + license).css('font-weight', 'normal');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to use Ajax to persist the updated state to the server. For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" class="save">
```

with:

```
$(":checkbox.save").click(function() {
  $.post('/save.php', {id: this.id, checked: this.checked});
  $("rowid").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Then when the server renders the page it can query the persisted page state and render the controls and rows correctly.

Comment: I'm using asp.net, and I'm not having a problem with getting the values persisted, it's just a matter of having them with the correct visibility after loading them, since theres no "click" happening on the checkbox.

Comment: @Barry: the best way is to use inline CSS (or even inline JS if you must) that is dynamically generated by the server to start things in the correct state. Alternatively you can add a function that will put everything int he correct state and call it in document ready.

Comment: I'm trying to do the second (a function called from document.ready) but I'm having a hard time getting to the right elements.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at livequery, which is a plugin for jquery:
[Livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

Answer (score 0):

Put the items you want to hide in a DIV and hide the DIV, not the table cell.